# Grava mais registros que o Necessario no meu DB

Tags: delphi, xml, nfe

Segue o código:

```delphi
// Leitura Dados Itens da Nota Fiscal...
xmlNCab := NoPrinc.ChildNodes.FindNode('det');
while not (xmlNCab = Nil) do
begin
    inc(l);
    sgProds.RowCount := l;
    //xmlNCab.ChildNodes.FindNode('det');
    xmlNItm := xmlNCab.ChildNodes['prod'];

    cProd := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['cProd'  ].Text; // Código do produto CFOP
    xProd := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['xProd'  ].Text; // Nome do produto
    uCom := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['uCom'    ].Text; // Sigla unidade da embalagem
    qCom := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['qCom'    ].Text; // Quantidade do produto (4dec,S/M)
    vUnCom := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['vUnCom'].Text; // Valor unitário do produto (4dec,S/M)
    vProd := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['vProd'  ].Text; // Valor total do produto (2dec,S/M)

    sgProds.Cells[0,l] := cProd;
    sgProds.Cells[1,l] := xProd;
    sgProds.Cells[2,l] := uCom;
    sgProds.Cells[3,l] := qCom;
    sgProds.Cells[4,l] := vUnCom;
    sgProds.Cells[5,l] := vProd;

    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.Close;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.SQL.Clear;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO xmlprod(cProd, xProd, uCom, qCom, ' + 'vUnCom, vProd, chval)');
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.SQL.Add('VALUES (:pcProd, :pxProd, :puCom, :pqCom, ' + ':pvUnCom, :pvProd, :pchval)');
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pcProd').AsString := cProd;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pxProd').AsString := xProd;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('puCom').AsString := uCom;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pqCom').AsString := qCom;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pvUnCom').AsString := Trcpv(vUnCom);
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pvProd').AsString := Trcpv(vProd);
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pchval').AsString := cnpj+fone;
    DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ExecSQL;

    xmlNCab := xmlNCab.NextSibling;
end;
```

Este código acima é apenas uma pequena continuação da resposta desta pergunta feita anteriormente:
[Access Violation ao Selecionar o arquivo XML - NFe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21306/access-violation-ao-selecionar-o-arquivo-xml-nfe/21315#21315)

E acredito que o erro esta neste while, pois ele seleciona os itens do meu xml, porém, quando tem apenas um item, ele seleciona mais que o necessário, ou seja, acrescenta de alguma forma, itens vazios.

Segue imagem do ocorrido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventualmente acabei descobrindo por mim mesmo.

Segue o código:

```cs
// Leitura Dados Itens da Nota Fiscal...
  // Aqui eu peço para encontrar a primeira ocorrencia da Tag <det>>
  xmlNCab := NoPrinc.ChildNodes.FindNode('det');
  // Posiciona o primeiro elemento encontrado
  xmlNCab.ChildNodes.First;
  repeat
    // referencia a tag <prod> dentro de <det>
    xmlNItm := xmlNCab.ChildNodes['prod'];
    xmlNItm.ChildNodes.First;

    inc(l);
    sgProds.RowCount := l;

    repeat
      if xmlNItm.ChildNodes['xProd'].text <> ''
      then
      begin
        cProd := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['cProd'  ].Text; // Código do produto CFOP
        xProd := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['xProd'  ].Text; // Nome do produto
        uCom := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['uCom'    ].Text; // Sigla unidade da embalagem
        qCom := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['qCom'    ].Text; // Quantidade do produto (4dec,S/M)
        vUnCom := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['vUnCom'].Text; // Valor unitário do produto (4dec,S/M)
        vProd := xmlNItm.ChildNodes['vProd'  ].Text; // Valor total do produto (
        //2dec,S/M)

        sgProds.Cells[0,l] := cProd;
        sgProds.Cells[1,l] := xProd;
        sgProds.Cells[2,l] := uCom;
        sgProds.Cells[3,l] := qCom;
        sgProds.Cells[4,l] := vUnCom;
        sgProds.Cells[5,l] := vProd;

        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.Close;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.SQL.Clear;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO xmlprod(cProd, xProd, uCom, qCom, ' +
          'vUnCom, vProd, chval)');
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.SQL.Add('VALUES (:pcProd, :pxProd, :puCom, :pqCom, ' +
          ':pvUnCom, :pvProd, :pchval)');
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pcProd').AsString := cProd;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pxProd').AsString := xProd;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('puCom').AsString := uCom;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pqCom').AsString := qCom;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pvUnCom').AsString := Trcpv(vUnCom);
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pvProd').AsString := Trcpv(vProd);
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ParamByName('pchval').AsString := cnpj+fone;
        DataModule1.zqInsertXML.ExecSQL;
      end;

      xmlNItm := xmlNItm.NextSibling;
    until xmlNItm = nil;
    xmlNCab := xmlNCab.NextSibling;
  until xmlNCab = nil;
```